# How to return list inside subscribe Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-router, angular-http

```
winServiceInfo() {
    this.dataArrs=[]
    this.winServiceURL = JSON.parse(this.WinService[0].windowsServicesInfo)["Stactuscheck"];
    this.service.getWinServicesInfo(this.winServiceURL)
    .pipe(
      catchError(this.handleError)
    )
    .subscribe((data: any) => {
        this.setSubscribeData(data);
        console.log(this.dataArrs)
    });
    console.log(this.dataArrs)
    return this.dataArrs;
}

setSubscribeData(data): any {
    this.WinService = data.windowsServicesInfo;
    this.dataArrs = this.getKeyValJsonObj();
return this.dataArrs;
}
```

the first console.log(this.dataArrs) retuens Arrar(3) but the second console.log(this.dataArrs) returns Arrar(0). I understand that subscribe is an asynchronous operation and for that reason.

So how to handle the situation to return the Array(3) from second console.log(this.dataArrs)

Answer (score 1):

instead of subscribing inside the function you need to return the `Observable`

```
this.dataArrs = winServiceInfo() {
  this.winServiceURL = 
  JSON.parse(this.WinService[0].windowsServicesInfo)["Stactuscheck"];
  return this.service.getWinServicesInfo(this.winServiceURL)
     .pipe(
        catchError(this.handleError)
          );
}
```

and in your template:

```
<tr *ngFor="let opc of dataArrs | async"> <tr>
```

and however call this function can `subscribe` to get the data

Comment: Either that or use the `async` pipe if applicable.

Comment: Still facing the same issue
 
 
 
winServiceInfo(j: number) {
 this.winServiceURL = SON.parse(this.WinService[j].windowsServicesInfo["Stactuscheck"];
 return this.service.getWinServicesInfo(this.winServiceURL)
   .pipe(
  catchError(this.handleError)
 )
   }

setSubscribeData(j: number): any {
 this.winServiceInfo(j).subscribe((data: any) => {
   this.WinService = data.windowsServicesInfo;
   this.dataArrs = this.getKeyValJsonObj();
   console.log(this.dataArr)
   return this.dataArrs;
 })
 console.log(this.dataArr)
};

Comment: @Eli Porush still facing the same issue

Comment: can you share the way you dispaly this data?

Comment: @Eli Porush I want to call winServiceInfo() on html page to get the list data
 
 <tr *ngFor="let opc of this.winServiceInfo(j);index as i">
                       
<tr>

getting an error
core.js:4002 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'windowsServicesInfo')
Typescript code